# Where are the "==" characters in my base64-encoded value coming from?

Tags: apex, encodingutil, encoding, twitter

I created a utility method [`TwitterUtil.encodeConsumerKeyAndSecret()`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b60d00a4009d4ae2dac) to return the encoded credentials needed for Twitter's [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) flow. However, when testing my method using the values in Twitter's [example](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only), the Apex test fails with the following message:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw, Actual: eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==

The entire process worked beautifully except for the presence of the "==" characters at the end of the base64-encoded value returned by my method. All I'm doing is using `EncodingUtil.urlEncode()` and `EncodingUtil.base64Encode()` to transform the consumer key and secret, so what is the reason for my method returning the extra "==" characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a newbie copy/paste error. I double-clicked the final value on Twitter's [documentation page](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) to select it, so that I could copy the value and paste it into my Apex test.

[image]

However, double-clicking the value in Chrome selected everything *except* for the final two "==" characters.

[image]

So, basically, the test failure was caused by me not copying the correct value from the API docs.